# R: read in quotes from .txt without backslash

Tags: regex, r, escaping, quotes, backslash

I have the string `(?<=k)(",V,")(?=p)` saved in a table in .txt `file` -- for the sake of simplicity let's say it is in row 1 column 1. I read in `file` using `read.table` with `quote=""`. I wanted to use `paste0(file[1,1])` to return the string `"(?<=k)(",V,")(?=p)"`. But instead, R keeps giving me `"(?<=k)(\",V,\")(?=p)"`, with a backslash before the two quotes originally from `file`. What can I do to read in quotes from a .txt *literally*? Thanks!

UPDATE:

I changed the string to `"(?<=k)(",V,")(?=p)"` in `file`, with 4 instead of 2 original quotes. After reading it in, I followed MichaelVE's suggestion and used `cat()`:

`cat(paste0(file[1,1]))`

This did give me the sequence I wanted:

`"(?<=k)(",V,")(?=p)"`

But I can't use the output in another function like `gsub` because it's not a character string -- In fact I have no idea what it is. Any idea on how to convert it to something usable?

Answer (score 2):

This is just a way for R to "read" the quotation marks within a character string.

I believe using cat(x) will do the trick in which x is your string. This will format your string to the 'end-user' format.

Comment: `cat()` returns `NULL`, so you lose the output if you assign it

Comment: That doesn't happen with me. cat("(?<=k)(\",V,\")(?=p)") will result in the correct string he was asking for.

Comment: Try `x <- cat("(?<=k)(\",V,\")(?=p)"); x`

Comment: I get your point, cat() is indeed only for output and not to save it as a new string. If it would be a new string you would end up with the input since R would convert it back to the non-printable characters

Comment: You can try using the minify() function from the [jsonlite](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/jsonlite/jsonlite.pdf) package. This will get rid of the pesky backslashes and return output to a variable.

Answer (score 2):

`\"` is one of the "non-printable" characters described in `?Quotes`.

> ...  backslash is used to escape the following character inside character constants
>
> Backslash is used to start an escape sequence inside character constants.
>
> Single quotes need to be escaped by backslash in single-quoted strings, and double quotes in double-quoted strings

Certain characters need to start with an escape sequence when inside character constants.

For example, try to assign it with embedded double quotes and you get an error

```
x <- "(?<=k)(",V,")(?=p)"
# Error: unexpected ',' in "x <- "(?<=k)(","
```

So we can either quote it in single quotes, or escape the embedded quotes.

```
x <- '(?<=k)(",V,")(?=p)'
x
# [1] "(?<=k)(\",V,\")(?=p)"
```

Now for "usable" and assignable output, it would be better to use `print()`, as `cat()` returns `NULL`. But beware that the escapes are still there, and you can't get rid of them.

```
p <- print(x, quote=FALSE)
# [1] (?<=k)(",V,")(?=p)
p
# [1] "(?<=k)(\",V,\")(?=p)"
```

Comment: Ah I see. I was hoping `"(?<=k)(",V,")(?=p)"` would work from .txt b/c it did if I typed it into the R console:

`V <- '[aeiou]'`

`paste0("(?<=l)(",V,")(?=st)")`

`> [1] "(?<=l)([aeiou])(?=st)"`

The output could in turn be used to match all but the last word here:

`lVst <- c('last','lest','list','lost','lust','lyst')`

`grep(paste0("(?<=l)(",V,")(?=st)"),lVst,perl=T)`

`[1] 1 2 3 4 5`

This basically is a somewhat awkward way for me to customize a char class without having to type the chars out (b/c R won't allow custom regex). It would've looked nicer if I can save it in .txt. Oh well...

Answer (score 0):

check ?read.table for 'quote' argument.

quote
the set of quoting characters. To disable quoting altogether, use quote = "". See scan for the behaviour on quotes embedded in quotes. Quoting is only considered for columns read as character, which is all of them unless colClasses is specified.

## EDIT:

```
df <- read.table("myfile.txt", 
                 header = TRUE,
                 sep = "\t", 
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
                 quote = "")
df[1,1]
[1] "(?<=k)(\",V,\")(?=p)"  

df <- read.table("myfile.txt", 
                 header = TRUE,
                 sep = "\t", 
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
                 quote = "\"")

df[1,1]
[1] "(?<=k)(,V,)(?=p)"
```

## EDIT2

```
df <- read.table("myfile.txt", 
                 header = TRUE,
                 sep = "\t", 
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
                 quote = "\"")

dput(df)
structure(list(Filename = c("(?<=k)(,V,)(?=p)", "(?<=k)(,V,)(?=p)", 
"(?<=k)(,V,)(?=p)", "(?<=k)(,V,)(?=p)", "(?<=k)(,V,)(?=p)", "(?<=k)(,V,)(?=p)"
)), .Names = "Filename", class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))

str(df)
'data.frame':   6 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ Filename: chr  "(?<=k)(,V,)(?=p)" "(?<=k)(,V,)(?=p)" "(?<=k)(,V,)(?=p)" "(?<=k)(,V,)(?=p)" ...

df[1,1]
[1] "(?<=k)(,V,)(?=p)"

str(df[1,1])
 chr "(?<=k)(,V,)(?=p)"

gsub("[(\")]", '', df[1,1])

[1] "?<=k,V,?=p"
```